# Who to create a dynamic array and resize it in Mosel Xpress IVE?

Tags: xpressive, mosel

I'm trying to create a dynamic array with size 5 `( x : dynamic array(5) of integer)`, i initialize array with `x(1)=1,x(2)=4,x(3)=1,x(4)=2,x(5)=3`.

Thanks to that I want to solve a problem. Then, in the same programme, I want to increase the die size of this array to 7 to add another value `x(6)=2,x(7)=3`, please providing me an algorithm that can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this form:

```
declarations
  x: dynamic array(R:range) of integer
end-declarations
x(1):=1; x(2):=4; x(3):=1; x(4):=2; x(5):=3
```

and then later on

```
x(6):=2; x(7):=3
```

Note that if 'x' is meant to be an array of decision variables in an optimization problem, then you need to declare the array with type 'mpvar', in which case the entries of the dynamic array cannot be specified by assignment but must be created explicitly:

```
declarations
  x: dynamic array(R:range) of mpvar
end-declarations
forall(i in 1..5) do
  create(x(i))
  x(i) is_integer           ! To state that variables are discrete
end-do
x(1)=1; x(2)=4; x(3)=1; x(4)=2; x(5)=3
```